# Probability of i.i.d. continuous random variables being the maximum

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ be i.i.d. continuous random variable with common probability density $f_X$. What is:
>
> - $P(X_2 = \max\{X_1,X_2\})$?
> - $P(X_n = \max\{X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots, X_n\})$?

Are these the same as saying $P(X_2 > X_1)$ and $P(X_n > X_1,X_2,X_3, \ldots, X_{n-1})$?  I am also confused about the difference between $P(X_2 = \max\{X_1,X_2\})$ and $P(Y = \max\{X_1,X_2\})$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is the same (note that you should remove $X_n$ in the right-hand-side of $P[X_n > X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n-1}, X_n]$ to make it $P[X_n> X_1, ..., X_{n-1}]$, this was likely a typo). There is no $Y$ defined and so $P[Y = \max[X_1, X_2]]$ makes no sense. Note that, since the random variables are continuous, the probability that they are all distinct is 1.

Comment: How do you find $P(X_2 = max\{X_1,X_2\})$? $P(X_n = max\{X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots, X_n\})$?

Comment: Notice that $P(X_i=\max\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\})$ has the same value for any $i=1,\cdots,n$, since $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ are i.i.d. Also they sum up to $1$. So it follows that $$P(X_i=\max\{X_1,\cdots,X_n\})=\frac{1}{n}.$$ In other words, anyone can be the maximum with equal probabilities. (This is no longer true if $X_k$'s assume a discrete distribution.) Also, as for your final question, the answer does depend on what $Y$ is.

Comment: What about $P(X_1 = max{X_1,X_2})$? Given the same condition.

Comment: As I mentioned above, we have $$P(X_1=\max\{X_1,X_2\})=P(X_2=\max\{X_1,X_2\})=\frac{1}{2},$$ i.e., any of $X_1$ and $X_2$ has equal chance of being the maximum.

Comment: I was trying to do $P(X_2 < x) = P(X_1 < x, X_2 < x ) = P(X_1 < x)P(X_2 < x) = F_X(x)^2$, which is the CDF, and then differentiating it give $2F_X(x)f_X(x)$. Did I do anything wrong? Or is it not the right approach?

Comment: The "right approach" is to note by symmetry that $\mathbb P(X_i=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)) = \frac1n$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$. (And of course, that this only holds when $X_1$ is absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a straightforward proof.

Let $f(x)$ be the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), $F(x)$ be the [cdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).

$P(X_n \ge \max_{1\le i\le n-1}X_i) = P(X_n \ge X_i, 1\le i\le n-1) = \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} f(x_n)dx_n \; \Pi_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_{-\inf}^{x_n}f(x_i)dx_i = \int_{-\inf}^{+\inf} f(x_n)dx_n F^{n-1}(x_n)=\frac{1}{n}F^n(x_n)|_{-inf}^{+inf} = \frac{1}{n}.$

Since the random variable is continuous, it makes no difference between equality and inequality. So $P(X_n \ge \max_{1\le i\le n-1}X_i) = P(X_n >\max_{1\le i\le n-1}X_i) = P(X_n = \max_{1\le i\le n}X_i) = \frac{1}{n}.$