# $\Pr(X>Y|Y>Z)$ for independent random variables $X, Y$ and $Z$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose we have three independent random variables, $X, Y$ and $Z$, that are all uniformly distributed over the unit interval (I'm not sure the specific distribution actually makes a difference).
I'm interested in the conditional probability $\Pr(X>Y|Y>Z)$.
I can think of a few ways of calculating this but, unfortunately, each approach gives a different answer.

1. $\Pr(X>Y|Y>Z)=\Pr(X>Y>Z)=\frac{1}{3!}=\frac{1}{6}$;
2. $\Pr(X>Y|Y>Z)=\Pr(X>\max\{Y, Z\})=\frac{1}{3}$; and,
3. $\Pr(X>Y|Y>Z)=\Pr(X>Y)\Pr(Y>Z)=\frac{1}{4}$.

My intuition suggests that approach 3 is incorrect, but I couldn't explain why. My hunch is that the events $X>Y$ and $Y>Z$ are not independent.
The difference between approach 1 and approach 2 seems to be that in 1 I have fixed the order of $Y>Z$, but for 2 it could also be $Z>Y$, and hence the equivalent expression would be $2/3!=1/3$.
However, maybe none of these approaches are correct!

Comment: Hint:  all possible orders are equally likely, there are three in which $Y>Z$.  How many of those also have $X>Y$?

Comment: To your comment:  Of course $X>Y$ and $Y>Z$ are not independent.  Knowing that $Y>Z$ is evidence, not proof, that $Y$ is large.  Knowing that $Y$ is probably large changes your view on the relative size of $X,Y$.

Comment: `---Z---Y---` : there are three possible (equally likely) positions for X.  Consider also the twin problem: if $~Y > Z,~$ what is the probability that $~X > Z~?$  Consider also, the associated conditional probability problem: what is the probability that $~X > Y,~$ given that there is a (1/2) probability that $~Y > Z,~$ and a (1/2) probability that $~Z > Y ~?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition of conditional probability,
$$
    P(X > Y \vert Y > Z) = \dfrac{P(X > Y, Y > Z)}{P(Y > Z)}
$$
Now, since $X, Y, Z$ are independent random variables, we have
$$
    P(X > Y, Y > Z) = \int_0^1 \int_0^x \int_0^y dzdydx = \dfrac{1}{6}
$$
Similarly,
$$
   P(Y > Z) = \int_0^1 \int_0^y dzdy = \int_0^1 ydy = \dfrac{1}{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
    P(X > Y \vert Y > Z) = \dfrac{1}{3}
$$

Comment: Many thanks for this clear and concise answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the comments:

By symmetry, the six possible orderings of $X,Y,Z$ are all equally likely, each has probability $\frac 16$.  Those with $Y>Z$ are $$X>Y>Z\quad \quad Y>X>Z\quad \quad  Y>Z>X$$

Of those, only $X>Y>Z$ satisfies $X>Y$, so the answer is $\frac 13$.

I note that your method ($2$) claims to yield $\frac 13$, but I do not understand the method.  Knowing that $X>\max (Y,Z)$ does not tell you that $X>Y>Z$.  Further argument is needed in order to establish that this answers the question.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments and answer. The second method I adapted from this answer to a similar question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542403/probability-of-i-i-d-continuous-random-variables-being-the-maximum